showing fields with x remaining days in Grafana
I'm creating a grafana table that will show accounts with the remaining time left before expiration, using the column override Standard options > Unit : From Now to display time remaining before timestamp is reached. The timestamp is shown as something like this: 2024/12/03-03:19:36
Here is my query with a sample output:
SELECT
  account_id as account,
  expiration_timestamp as expiry_date
FROM `project_id.ad_account_exp.accounts`
GROUP BY
  account_id,expiration_timestamp




account_id
expiration_timestamp




account01
2 days ago


account02
1 day ago


account03
in 5 days


account04
in 7 days


account05
in 9 days


account06
in 14 days


account07
in 17 days


account08
in 25 days



Is there a filter or query that will allow me to display only accounts that are expiring in 10 days or less, also excluding accounts that are expired? Thus showing:



account_id
expiration_timestamp




account03
in 5 days


account04
in 7 days


account05
in 9 days



Thanks in advance!

I don't think so. But you can put this filtration into your SQL query.
